# TypeScript Template Literals break generic constraints

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I am trying to write a Sub-Pub class that supports events AND sub-events denoted by the following syntax:

```
publisher.on("message:general", ... ) // subscribe to all messages
publisher.on("message", ... ) // subscribe to messages in general
```

To do this, I am using TypeScript template literals.

The issue is that while it broadly works, it seems to break generic constraints. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is what it looks like so far:

[TS Playground link for convenience](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgDOyA3gFDLIID2IIECYAXKRZcgK6HQuFhSgA5gG42AX1GUAJsEI06DZq3aduUXvyGT2UCHEK0WAIgBGcBVKPIAPsiNhgAWwjUOYK7aMAbPfiPaJMjEyMikGLzhdZDAATwAHFAwsPAIwZABeZABrCBjqGDRMHHwiUTJQSFhEFABlDhMUomQIAA9IECliACUGaigpAB4k4tSAGmQ+ARBBAD5lKlp6RmNBAmg4Lw87AHcsaBpqHygt72oTExj-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)

```
interface ChatEvents {
  connect: {
    user: string;
  };
  disconnect: {
    user: string;
    reason: "banned" | "timeout" | "leave";
  };
}

declare type ChatEvent = keyof ChatEvents;

interface SubEvents extends Record<ChatEvent, string> {
  connect: "general" | "watercooler" | "lobby";
  disconnect: "voice" | "text";
}

declare type EventWithSubEvent<T extends ChatEvent> = `${T}${
  | ""
  | `:${SubEvents[T]}`}`;

// "connect" | "connect:general" | "connect:watercooler" | "connect:lobby"
declare type ChatConnectEvent = EventWithSubEvent<"connect">;
// "disconnect" | "disconnect:voice" | "disconnect:text"
declare type ChatDisconnectEvent = EventWithSubEvent<"disconnect">;

// So far so good!

// Let's write some generics:
declare function subscribeToEvent<E extends ChatEvent>(
  event: E,
  callback: (payload: ChatEvents[E]) => void
): void;

subscribeToEvent("connect", (payload) => {
    // Correctly extracts matching type
    type TPayload = typeof payload; // { user: string; }
});

declare function subscribeToSubEvent<E extends ChatEvent>(
  event: EventWithSubEvent<E>,
  callback: (payload: ChatEvents[E]) => void
): void;

subscribeToSubEvent("connect:general", (payload) => {
    // Extracts all possible payload types instead of only the `connect` one
    /*
        {
            user: string;
        } | {
            user: string;
            reason: "banned" | "timeout" | "leave";
        }
    */
    type TPayload = typeof payload;
});

subscribeToSubEvent("connect:voice", () => {}) // Should fail but doesn't. `:voice` is a subevent of `disconnect`, not `connect`.
```

Comment: I think the problem can be reduced to line #18, paste this below and see the resulting types:
`type X = EventWithSubEvent<ChatEvent>` this type is too wide

Answer (score 2):

First the reason this didn't work is that `EventWithSubEvent<ChatEvent>` expands in not the way you want, `SubEvents["connect" | "disconnect"]` directly gives the subevents of both main events so it returns a union of all possible subevents and then the string templates sees a union of `"connect" | "disconnect"` concatenated with a union of all the possible sub events, so it ends up pairing every combination not just the ones that match up. One way to fix this is to instead loop over each option in the union and apply that logic individually. [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgDOyA3gFDLIID2IIECYAXKRZcgK6HQuFhSgA5gG42AX1GUAJsEI06DZq3aduUXvyGT2UCHEK0WAIgBGcBVKPIAPsiNhgAWwjUOYK7aMAbPfiPaJMjEyMikGLzhdZDAATwAHFAwsPAIwZABeZABrCBjqGDRMHHwiUTJQSFhEFABlDhMUomQIAA9IECliACUGaigpAB4k4tSAGmQ+ARBBAD5lKlp6RmNBAmg4Lw87AHcsaBpqHygt72oTExj-Nhk5RcVjXGpgJBPINqvggHpP5G2i5DyHF+0BQfWAglAGy8MWQUie01C4UiKFiCWQjTAAHVgGB0HUGiUsX1uAMACrNNoETqFZKEuaZAAGABISKSxCy2J4jJzkAymCz8RjCABtUkAXTEDMlZW+yEccDixD0CHQzR8znAyHy0XQKA4IGAtGQoGQ5LA1B1KAghOIoBkuGAUg4UJhuII0TgOWI+sNIC1BShWriDloxDgMEqZFloD4eik-opcXMMmmlt+6EOKG4aQqFrgyC8OPWXmNftoKEE1AAdIiEBEoqiUBjsbjBYSAEIQMCVMkU9rU4YY+mkYUAaVLprFLGbOLx9WbxIgA1HMzEorFIUbyExAAkAIKkgD6AE0APIAVUP+4AIhl0YSW3OCalMYuhkUh1GfpQAHoAfjILddwPE8L0PTE9wAOVJbBb0yGdW3nDsux7Qc6S-dh-03eImwfWc21SXtWn7Yg0NSYcEKfDFO27aAyRmGUfiMeQlncGw7BY+5VnoKANhOTjll2SoDiOfi7mWLwzgubkwjrZFohwmkwFQcSRk1eC8MQ59wAGZjVKMBiMKMG4BLYzwTNUphHmeCATgshRljedxa3rFFFOGa9ZFMjE70ogidOMrz9MMjCagteAoAmC1K2oKQAEIQllAAZLsAHJiG2ARICi5xkG46BnkIJgXPkmB9UYX0JnqOQBBMCBSWoDEBmwPsqVIj86QACjYa1UmnUY2AQKEzAQLIWE6pMYkkuApBYMiiGFbAxQASgyOZrKkMhlpYDaykIaqEFq+rGsJTq9Ic9xxgmuApuoGbVvSOZyBUWUVKgXRGGhPteMYYh5TAFUhAUhI2EoLdSQABRu6b40yRttUmmHhGQWUSFUHgJk0aZkeCMRlrKWTXOQMqQAqo19pMGrgDqhr-LAZrWo6draXI7rKF68Bp00qjCWamYBsoIavC8EaxuQa7bpmuaOtSEUloe9ank27bkF2kIKapmnqDps7TKYfLeM2K7EbuqQFfmShZWwNofrAMNheQOJqEIQhqZ8R3odN4GIFtEBYxmhNaC+t1eVMhktXoUGUYAKijlRnpURPKC4DHJi0OP2DEdiE6TlQU-UTGphEDOk90fRDDsMwLFeJwXDcE4fDgPxtCT4IVGjz4o-BqHJdh72Ec9mbRDxvaDqO2mkNSXXLOsl4rvNkg8ZRn4agzDgvHjeBgBLEw3FhagfZAVKwCrXkrKeJBw9kZB8wpjm0m1Bl7NYhlxhAag0gZMOqyAA)

```
// what you were originally doing
declare type EventWithSubEventWorse<T extends ChatEvent> = `${T}${
  | ""
  | `:${SubEvents[T]}`}`;

// maps each element of the union in T to the events individually then takes union of all options after
// instead of expanding the whole set into a literal in one go.
declare type EventWithSubEventBetter<T extends ChatEvent> = {[K in T]: EventWithSubEventWorse<K>}[T]

type WHAT_YOU_HAD = EventWithSubEventWorse<ChatEvent>
type WHAT_YOU_WANTED = EventWithSubEventBetter<ChatEvent>

type EventWithSubEvent<T extends ChatEvent> = EventWithSubEventBetter<T>;
```

This means if we removed the generic from our function and just said the first argument has to be `EventWithSubEvent<ChatEvent>` it only lists the valid options, however it doesn't provide the best intellisense support because if you are in the middle of writing the code and there is a state where you are not passing a valid string typescript just has no idea what the generic should actually be since it has to know the generic to generate valid options for the first argument. So we can do a bit better.

Generally I've found that the less typescript has to work to deduce a generic type from arguments, the more generics just work (especially for providing decent intellisense aid).  In this case if you setup the generic to be the exact text passed as the first argument (constrained to all valid options using the object literal thingy) then use a helper type to extract just the `'connect' | 'disconnect'` part to use in the callback it will work much smoother.  ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgDOyA3gFDLIID2IIECYAXKRZcgK6HQuFhSgA5gG42AX1GUAJsEI06DZq3aduUXvyGT2UCHEK0WAIgBGcBVKPIAPsiNhgAWwjUOYK7aMAbPfiPaJMjEyUEhYRBQAZQ4TPAIwYggAD0gQKWIAJQZqKCkAHgBrCABPahg0TBx8IgAaZD4BEEEAPmUqWnpGY0ECaDgvDzsAdyxoGmofKEHvahMTYv82GTkOxWNcamAkacgUxeCwYoAHFABBLy8MLDiiZABeUgBtAGlkUGQi0vKrqvjCAF0WK9bAADAAkJGeYiYEOisWqCRe-zEILEj0+ZQq1wRALIZAA9PjkOgIF4TlBkGBqMhkvxEGBKSTkAByeSdMDM6zM5ZsxTM5AwKDURzIcw0hFkQ4nZDYFJQel4MB5AAqNJSBHSyHOl0qNwSrQeqtpGuIGO+upxyAA-MhVSwjeq0sRwSRQDBoFroRCGkIUdatcgWPR8FAyFIGF44LoBRwQIxgLR6jE5AITBBldQ4Xq8tg1alNdqfnrCM0ABRsCAIljYGpsBD9LxmBAFFilo5wYpeahwKQsIs4x6yumMRU55r-ACU91aG2AUjIE5Ys6kojIhGTCFT6czMT1paMPNWXVn2zqbY7XZ7U7urXIlHkBh8ADou4Jz53u1In7p9LQp4TkHDSBGGIMBKhZQ8FEYflZEZFB2w-HtKWOCAggnVd1xMFNgDTDMswRfdeWPTZT2QUtr1vMR-yJeBgC8YgjiFckvGKZA8SAA))

```
interface ChatEvents {
  connect: {
    user: string;
  };
  disconnect: {
    user: string;
    reason: "banned" | "timeout" | "leave";
  };
}
interface SubEvents extends Record<keyof ChatEvents, string> {
  connect: "general" | "watercooler" | "lobby";
  disconnect: "voice" | "text";
}
type AllChatEvents = {[K in keyof ChatEvents]: K | `${K}:${SubEvents[K]}`}[keyof ChatEvents]

// helper to extract the 'connect'|'disconnect' from an event
type ExtractEvt<T extends AllChatEvents> = T extends keyof ChatEvents ? T : T extends `${infer A}:${string}` ? A : never
declare function subscribeToSubEvent<E extends AllChatEvents>(
  event: E,
  callback: (payload: ChatEvents[ExtractEvt<E>]) => void
): void;

subscribeToSubEvent("disconnect:voice", (payload) => {
  console.log(payload.reason) // detects that 'disconnect' is the payload type
});

subscribeToSubEvent("connect:voice", () => {}) // fails properly
```

As a bonus, because the generic constraint is all valid strings to be passed intellisense will give very useful results compared to other generics setups where it can't figure out what the correct behaviour is until you've already typed it:

[image: showing auto-complete list between empty quotes as first argument to subscribeToSubEvent function and that it suggests all valid options]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution.

The problem is that apparently template types do not [distribute over unions](https://www.ayubbegimkulov.com/type-distribution-guide/)

To work around the issue take a look at this simplified [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=54&pln=18&pc=102#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgDOyA3gFDLIID2IIECYAXKRZcgK6HQuFhSgA5gG42AX1GUAJsEI06DZq3aduUXvyGT2UCHEK0WAIgBGcBVKPIAPsiNhgAWwjUOYK7aMAbPfiPaJMjEyMikGLzhdZDAATwAHFAwsPAIwZABeZABrCBjqGDRMHHwiUTJQSFhEFABlDhMUomQIAA9IECliACUGaigpAB4k4tSAGmQ%20ARBBAD5lKlp6RmNBAmg4Lw87AHcsaBpqHygt72oTExj-Nhk5RcVjXGpgJBPINqvg0PDIlFiE5EaYAA6sAwOg6g0SmABgAVZptAidQrJKFzTJw1rtJHmGLIAD8yAABgASEgwsRMUkQwGEADaMIAumJCcgWPR8FBRH8UAANDIAqEgsHUqEDADk8iWYDFNmQYpuksUYpmZAA9Kq7Irlqt6FANictcxdpUDkcDXdll4zhdzQplo9nhBbVKmG93LKjAqLcwdetNh6vXajXsoKboCdAy6redLgHZIamA6XnHbkHXZijCEyNzkDyAIz8wFC8H1QHiw3KtUaowJ316-2eBPG-bUQ7hj0J6M2kI5nkAJkLgtBJchqXFkaVKvV0XivIHmU98e9iaeyc8E%20WbqMQA)

The trick is to specify the template type with generic type extending from any (just to force the union distribution)

```
declare type EventWithSubEvent<T extends ChatEvent> = T extends any ? `${T}:${SubEvents[T]}` : never;
```

This is [your fixed playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgDOyA3gFDLIID2IIECYAXKRZcgK6HQuFhSgA5gG42AX1GUAJsEI06DZq3aduUXvyGT2UCHEK0WAIgBGcBVKPIAPsiNhgAWwjUOYK7aMAbPfiPaJMjEyMikGLzhdZDAATwAHFAwsPAIwZABeZABrCBjqGDRMHHwiUTJQSFhEFABlDhMUomQIAA9IECliACUGaigpAB4k4tSAGmQ%20ARBBAD5lKlp6RmNBAmg4Lw87AHcsaBpqHygt72oTExj-Nhk5RcVjXGpgJBPINqvg0PDIlFiE5EaYAA6sAwOg6g0SmABgAVZptAidQrJKFzTJw1rtJHmGLIAD8yAABgASEgwsSktieIxUolMUkQwGEADaMIAumJCZyWPR8FAygB6AV2eRLdw2EV3ZarehQDYnUX3XaVA5HBVS5heM4XGlhBARKJ-RJFVAawEZAFQkFgxlQgZGRWMIwzURCuw3R3izwejVMR7PCAnH0KZZvdxffU-aLxY1YAAisk95sygOt4PqgPtwbFzsFwpq1GQ8CgE0Lgmo1CkAEIQm6ADIQMAAcmI2wEkFLzmQMugz0ITAjBpQMA4IEYwFoE3qcgEJggMOomew8KxxGGgJmAAo2BAoSxsKM2AgNl4zAgsixN3E4DEtXApCx11CWdg2QBKDJzf1SMhvljfspCGnBBZ3nRcoU3B0NSMcYrxvO8pA-dI5nIFQ3VNKBdEYLxcUxOVGGIRwsAQdAhGjBI2EoI1kBhAAFeDqHvC0jXyZBr1vRipGEZA3RIVQeAmTRpm44IxDfMo9SHItR3HScgJMGdgDnBdbVSAZl0xRE1yKDdt0oXdUn3K1QXTSE1OwGZD0oY8vFPRAL2QOCOPvR8dOfZlXyQr8nh-P9kAAkJ5MU5TqFU8BIM9JgezlTZYPYhCvPmSg3WwNp8LAYgTzY6hCEIJSfDYhimKNYhQD4PQpGQVjaBw6J0BQQlPUJKr6EoniACo2pUVCVF6yguAEyYtC69gxAlHq%20pUAb1EEqYRBGvrdH0Qw7DMCxXicFw3BOHw4D8bQ%20uCFR2oFNrqLoorKsyFiCnizjRDEwDgNAlSMwgqCQ2Yf0XlgxKSDEnj83QVwvEq%20BgC8ZATDcZApGoCBCBAJswAAOjpb6IGa2RkDgKc5yhKqCkJbNFEJcYQGoNJGo1QkUaAA)

Comment: Interestingly, your "fixed playground" link does not handle the payload type properly, while your simplified playground is. The only difference between the two is the optionality of the `:`

Comment: Writing `EventWithSubEvent<K> | K` as another way to make the `:` optional does not seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what is the problem?

Comment: The value of `TPayload`

Comment: @paroxyzm issue is that `subscribeToSubEvent("disconnect:voice", (p) => p.reason)` doesn't infer it is a disconnect event and therefore  `p.reason` isn't recognized as safe.